# How to pass an Integer Array to IN clause in MyBatis

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mybatis

There is a query in my Mybatis containing an IN clause which is basically a set of Id's ( Integers)

I am now stuck on how can I pass an Integer array to this IN clause so that it pulls up the proper records.Tried by passing a String containing the ID's to the IN clause , but this did not work as expected.

Code Sample below

Mybatis Method using Annotations

```
@Select(SEL_QUERY)
    @Results(value = {@Result(property="id",column="ID")})
    List<Integer> getIds(@Param("usrIds") Integer[] usrIds);
```

Query

```
select distinct ID from table a where a.id in ( #{usrIds} )
```

Method Call

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[2];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;

mapper.getIds(arr)
```

This is not working , Mybatis throws an error when I call the mapper method

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The [myBatis User Guide on Dynamic SQL](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html) has an example on how to use a foreach loop to build the query string, which works for lists and arrays.

Prior to release 3.2 you had to use xml configuration to use dynamic sql, with newer versions it should also be possible to use [dynamic sql in annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428742/how-to-use-annotations-with-ibatis-mybatis-for-an-in-query/22646475#22646475).

```
<select id="selectPostIn" resultType="domain.blog.Post">
    SELECT *
    FROM POST P
    WHERE ID in
    <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list"
             open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{item}
    </foreach>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check it out and update the space here

Comment: Actually, it also works with annotations as long as you make your query string start with `<script>`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22646475/80779), and also [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16032509/80779)

Comment: @LordOfThePigs: I could not find that in the official docs, do you have a link for that?

Comment: @JörnHorstmann To be honnest, I couldn't find the reference to that feature in the documentation, but it definitely works (and I use it frequently). Just check the two other questions I linked.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann There is a [extract from the mybatis-user mailing list](http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/Dynamic-queries-using-annotations-td4026489.html) that has some MyBatis devs telling someone how to use dynamic SQL with annotations, saying that it is supported starting from version 3.2.0, with version 3.2.1 introductiong the `<script>` tag in annotations.

Comment: That dzone article looks almost identical to the MyBatis official documentation. http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html

Comment: Hi Jörn Horstmann, thank you for the answer, but the link [**myBatis User Guide on Dynamic SQL**](http://www.mybatis.org/core/dynamic-sql.html) seems to be broken, not able to find a alternative for the same.

Comment: Er is there any **shorter** method...? Or can I make some shortcuts? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

YES, you can do that using annotations.

If you're using **postgresql**, you can do like [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3442136/439171).

If you're using **MySQL** try this changes in your code sample:

Mybatis Method using Annotations

```
@Select(SEL_QUERY)
    @Results(value = {@Result(property="id",column="ID")})
    List<Integer> getIds(@Param("usrIds") String usrIds);
```

Query (using MySQL)

```
select distinct ID from table a where FIND_IN_SET( a.id, #{usrIds}) <> 0
```

Method call

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[2];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;

String usrIds= "";
for (int id : ids) {
    usrIds += id + ",";
}

mapper.getIds(usrIds)
```

Comment: exactly what i needed

Comment: A valuable note here is that FIND_IN_SET will not use indexes so this version is likely to perform worse than an IN statement

Comment: FIND_IN_SET is the most easy way to do this (for those who don't care about performance)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new type handler and use it only for your parameter. The query would change to:

```
SELECT ... WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, #{usrIds, typeHandler=my.pkg.ListTypeHandler}) <> 0
```

And the type handler:

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.ObjectTypeHandler;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;

public class ListTypeHandler extends ObjectTypeHandler {
    @Override
    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Object parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        ps.setObject(i, Joiner.on(",").join((Iterable<?>) parameter), JdbcType.OTHER.TYPE_CODE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List distinctID = (List) getSqlSession().selectOne("dataMapper.getUniqueData", uniqueIDList);
```

Send the list of unique id

```
<select id="getUniqueData" resultType="List">
     select distinct ID from table a where a.id in 
      <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list"
          open="(" separator="," close=")">
            #{item}
      </foreach>
</select>
```

When using an List, **index** will be the number of current iteration and value **item** will be the element retrieved in this iteration