# How to use IN () in a query in myBatis

Tags: java, orm, mybatis

I have a requirement of using IN in a query which has a format of something like:

```
@Select("SELECT max(count) FROM whatevertable WHERE id IN (#{xyz})")
public int doSomething(List<Integer> xyz)
```

I tried searching but found all kinds of functions in XML but my requirement is using JAVA.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: See if this post is of help to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754814/how-to-pass-an-integer-array-to-in-clause-in-mybatis

Answer (score 1):

refer [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/ibatis-mybatis-working-dynamic)

```
SELECT id, title, author   
FROM article   
WHERE id_category
IN    
<foreach item="category" index="index" collection="list"   open="("  separator=","           cose=")">     
#{category}  
</foreach>
```