# mybatis foreach with annotations

Tags: mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

Does anybody know how the following xml configuration can be expressed with annotations?

```
<insert id="insertEmployeeList" parameterType="java.util.List">
INSERT ALL  
<foreach collection="list" item="element" index="index" >
INTO EMPLOYEE (id,name) values (#{element.id},#{element.name})
</foreach>
SELECT * FROM dual
</insert>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use dynamic SQL query in MyBatis with annotation(how to use selectProvider)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685655/how-to-use-dynamic-sql-query-in-mybatis-with-annotationhow-to-use-selectprovide)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Annotations with iBatis (myBatis) for an IN query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428742/how-to-use-annotations-with-ibatis-mybatis-for-an-in-query)