# Add default value when field is null with MyBatis

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I want to insert the default value from database when my field is null. I use an Oracle Database.

```
CREATE TABLE "EMPLOYEE" 
   ("COL1" VARCHAR2(800) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "COL2" VARCHAR2(100) DEFAULT NOT NULL 'toto', 
    CONSTRAINT "PK_EMPLOYEE" PRIMARY KEY ("COL1")
```

with a simple SQL request, we can write:

```
insert into EMPLOYEE(COL1,COL2) values ('titi', default)
```

How can i do this with annotations MyBatis in Spring? I must create an HandlerType?

Comment: Yeah. it is better if like spring could specify default value, e.g. `@Value("${mongodb.url:127.0.0.1}")`

Answer (score 3):

In mapper XML, build dynamically the SQL (add the col2 column and value when not null):

```
insert into employee (col1<if test="col2 != null">, col2</if>) 
values (#{COL1}<if test="col2 != null">, #{col2}</if>)
```

EDIT: since value in annotation must be constant, I used to think dynamic SQl was not possible in annotation, but there is a trick I have found here: [How to use dynamic SQL query in MyBatis with annotation(how to use selectProvider)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685655/how-to-use-dynamic-sql-query-in-mybatis-with-annotationhow-to-use-selectprovide)  and checked it myself.

To use dynamic SQL this into an annotation, surround it with "script" tags:

```
@Insert("<script>insert into employee (col1<if test='col2 != null'>, col2</if>) 
    values (#{COL1}<if test='col2 != null'>, #{col2}</if>)</script>")
```

In tests, just escape double quotes " or replace them with simple quotes '

Comment: Please read the question clearly, the OP asks the solution using annotations while you have posted for XML.

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you omit the `COL2` in your colum definition of the insert statement. Because the DB recognizes, that there is no value for the new row and it will apply the default value from the `create table` statement.

Have you tried something like this?

```
public interface EmployeeDAO {
   String INSERT = "insert into employee (col1) values (#{COL1})";

   @Insert(INSERT)
   public int insertDefault(PersonDO p) throws Exception;
}
```

Comment: Hello. I'm agree with you. But what do you do if my column COL2 is not null. How do you do your insertion? In fact the solution must manage the two cases: insert value of COL2 (if not null) or set the default value of COL2 (if null).

Comment: if COL2 is not null, you would have to call an insert statement, which uses COL2 and the value, or you need to create a typehandler. In the typehandler you handle the default value, if the appropriate value in the *DO is null.