# Can I pass a List as a parameter to a MyBatis mapper?

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm trying to define a simple `@Select` annotation in MyBatis to get a collection of objects based on criteria defined by an IN clause.  The SQL looks something like:

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employeeID IN (1, 2, 3);
```

The list is generated dynamically, so I don't know how many parameters it will have.  I'd like to just pass in a `List` of values, something like:

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employeeID IN( #{employeeIds} )")
List<Employee> selectSpecificEmployees(@Param("employeeIds") List<Integer> employeeIds);
```

I'm creating an instance of the `Mapper` where the annotation above is defined and calling it as follows:

```
List<Integer> empIds = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Employee> result = mapper.selectSpecificEmployees(empIds);
```

I've discovered that this doesn't work.

> org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:
>   ### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   ### The error may involve
>   com.mycompany.MySourceMapper.selectSpecificEmployees-Inline
>   ### The error occurred while setting parameters
>   ### Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:8)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:77)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:69)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForList(MapperMethod.java:85)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:65)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:35)
>       at $Proxy23.selectSpecificProductTypes(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mycompany.MySourceMapperDebug.testSelectSpecificEmployees(MySourceMapperDebug.java:60)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
>       at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
>       at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
>       at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
>       at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
>       at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
>       at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
>       at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.ibatis.type.UnknownTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter(UnknownTypeHandler.java:21)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:23)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.executor.parameter.DefaultParameterHandler.setParameters(DefaultParameterHandler.java:73)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.parameterize(PreparedStatementHandler.java:61)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.parameterize(RoutingStatementHandler.java:43)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:56)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:40)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:216)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:95)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:72)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation.proceed(Invocation.java:31)
>           ... 36 more

I think the problem is in the annotation itself.  This seems like it would be a fairly common requirement.  Do I need to convert the `List` to a `String` myself and pass that in as a `String` parameter instead of a `List<Integer>`?  Or is there some other syntax for passing a `List` as a parameter to a MyBatis annotation?

Comment: You can use both xml and annotation based config together look at this post please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788250/xml-annotation-based-configuration-for-mybatis/9076435

Answer (score 55):

I've never used annotations and MyBatis before; I've always gone the xml configuration file route (not implying there is anything wrong with using annotations; just explaining I can't help you there).

That being said, [page 46 from the MyBatis user guide](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html):

> **foreach**
>
> Another common necessity for dynamic SQL is the need to iterate over a
> collection, often to build an IN condition.  For example:

```
<select id="selectPostIn" resultType="domain.blog.Post">
    SELECT *
    FROM POST P
    WHERE ID in
    <foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list"
        open="(" separator="," close=")">
          #{item}
    </foreach>
  </select>
```

> The foreach element is very powerful, and allows you to specify a
> collection, declare item and index variables that can be used inside
> the body of the element.  It also allows you to specify opening and
> closing strings, and add a separator to place in between iterations.
> The element is smart in that it won’t accidentally append extra
> separators.

Comment: Do you know if mybatis can handle the limits in the IN clauses (like oracle is limited to 1000). I guess we should take care of it ourselves

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't know off of the top of my head.  This post was actually around the last time I used MyBatis so I'm rusty.  That being said, I'm sure if you opened the user guide I linked to and did a search for "limit", something would show up - if it were there.  That is my best guess.

Answer (score 6):

If you wish to use `foreach` and annotations, you can use this syntax:

```
@Select("<script>" +
         "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employeeID IN " +
           "<foreach item='item' index='index' collection='employeeIds'" +
             " open='(' separator=',' close=')'>" +
             " #{item}" +
           "</foreach>" +
         "</script>") 
List<Employee> selectSpecificEmployees(@Param("employeeIds") List<Integer> employeeIds);
```

(copied from that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22646475/1075341))

Answer (score 5):

With a bit of overhead you can use JAVA to build a dynamic String after processing the List.

1. Define a Select Provider where you can build your dynamic query:

   ```
   @SelectProvider(type = com.data.sqlprovider.EmployeeSQLBuilder.class, method =      
    "selectSpecificEmployees")
    List<Employee> selectSpecificEmployees(@Param("employeeIds") List<Integer> 
     employeeIds);
   ```
2. In com.data.sqlprovider.EmployeeSQLBuilder.class , Using StringBuilder, generate the query

   ```
    public String selectSpecificEmployees(Map<String, Object> parameters) {
       List<Integer> employeeIds = (List<Integer>) parameters.get("employeeIds");
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("SELECT id, name FROM employees where id IN (");
       for (int i : employeeIds) {
           builder.append(i + ",");
       }
       builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);

       builder.append(")");
       System.out.println(builder.toString());
       return builder.toString();
   }
   ```

Comment: Because the possible employeeIds are integers you can get away with this.  However, if these were strings you'd have a problem if the string has any special characters in it

Comment: concatenating parameter values in SQL string is evil. And if parameters are strings, this is the recipe for SQL injection.

Answer (score 5):

I'm facing the exact same issues recently.  For my understanding, you prefer to use `Java` mapper instead of `XML`, which is the same here.

Following is what I'm doing to deal with it using: [SqlBuilder](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/statement-builders.html).

**The sql builder class:**

```
public class EmployeeSqlBuilder {

    public String getEmployees(final List employeeIds) {

        String strSQL = new SQL() {{
            SELECT("*");
            FROM("employees");
            if (employeeIds != null) {
                WHERE(getSqlConditionCollection("employeeID", employeeIds));
            }
        }}.toString();

        return strSQL;
    }

    private String getSqlConditionCollection(String field, List conditions) {
        String strConditions = "";
        if (conditions != null && conditions.size() > 0) {
            int count = conditions.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                String condition = conditions.get(i).toString();

                strConditions += condition;
                if (i < count - 1) {
                    strConditions += ",";
                }
            }
            return field + " in (" + strConditions + ")";
        } else {
            return "1=1";
        }
    }

}
```

**The mapper:**

```
@SelectProvider(type = EmployeeSqlBuilder.class, method = "getEmployees")
List<RecordSubjectEx> getEmployees(@Param("employeeIds") List employeeIds);
```

That's it.

The `EmployeeSqlBuilder` will dynamically generate the sql statement.  I'm using a function  `getSqlConditionCollection` to do the logical manipulation.  Of course you can encapsulate the `getSqlConditionCollection` as a static function in a class, which is what I'm doing in real project, then you can use it easily from other SqlBuilder.

Answer (score -1):

MyBatis support List params directly.

Assume this is you dao layer:

```java
public List<User> getUsersByIds(List<Integer> ids);
```

you want to pass an ids list.
then, in you mapper.xml, you can just use them:

```xml
    <select id="getUsersByIds" resultType="entity.User">
      select * from user
      where id = #{list[0]} or id = #{list[1]}
    </select>
```

you can use `#{list[0]}` or `#{list[1]}` to get list value.

```java
    @Test
    public void getUsersByIds(){
        List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ids.add(1);
        ids.add(2);
        List<User> users = userDao.getUsersByIds(ids);
        // you will get correct result
    }
```

Comment: This is somewhat misleading statement since most people will be looking at `IN(#{list})` case which is not supported, so we're stuck with http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html?#foreach

Answer (score -2):

although this question is many years ago, and @Dave 's answer is right, but today i want to know how to sove it by java not xml config, i got it and share it to some of you.

```java
    @Autowired
    PersonMapper personMapper;

    @Test
    public void testListParams(){
        String[] ids = {"1","2","3","4"};
        List<String> idList = Arrays.asList(ids);
        String idListToString = idList.toString().substring(1, idList.toString().length() - 1);
        List<Person> people = personMapper.selectByIds(idListToString);
        people.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

in PersonMapper.java

```java
    @Select("select id,name,age from person where id in ( ${ids} )") // attention: here is $ not #, $ is use to replace with string, # is use to replace ? with param
    List<Person> selectByIds(@Param("ids") String ids);
```