# how to read generated sql statement from annotation-configured Mybatis mapper

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I'm using MyBatis 3.2.3 with Spring 3.2.5 with an annotation based configuration.

I have a few POJOs that call generated Mapper interfaces to execute SQL queries.
Is it possible to retrieve the SQL statement that's being executed by a mapper?  I could understand how to do this if I were using the 'old' approach where I had DAOs which extend SqlMapClientDaoSupport, but now that I'm using only mapper interfaces I'm not sure how I could get a reference to the generated SQL.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered implementing [Interceptor](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html)?

Comment: @ArunasJunevicius I did look at that briefly but wasn't sure how to configure such using annotations.  If you think that's the way forward I'll keep investigating along those lines

Comment: it's definitely [possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788250/xml-annotation-based-configuration-for-mybatis), even in more ways than the one discribed. And there's possibility to use AspectJ to intercept almost anything

Comment: thanks.  My problem at the moment is how to configure a plugin though I'm using annotation based configuration without mybatis-config.xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392919/how-to-configure-a-mybatis-plugin-in-annotation-based-configuration

Answer (score 2):

It's actually possible to do this in a Spring configured application without using a plugin/interceptor:

```
SqlSessionFactory s = (SqlSessionFactory) ctx.getBean("sqlSessionFactory");

Configuration configuration = s.getConfiguration(); 
MappedStatement ms = configuration.getMappedStatement("MyStatementId");


BoundSql boundSql = ms.getBoundSql(parameters); // pass parameters for the SQL statement
System.out.println("SQL" + boundSql.getSql());
```