# Mybatis, pass muliple list as parametres

Tags: xml, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-sql

String loadCandies(@Param("id") String id, @Param("varietyList") List varietyList, @Param("errorCode") List errorCodes)

How can I achieve this in mybatis xml, as for a single list in parameter we can directly use foreach tag in where tag clause but if there are 2 list like above, how can we achieve this?

Note* - for a single list already referred StackOverflow answer

[Can I pass a List as a parameter to a MyBatis mapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451042/can-i-pass-a-list-as-a-parameter-to-a-mybatis-mapper)

Comment: The parameter should just be wrapped in a `map` so you should be able to do a `foreach` using both `collection="varietyList"` and `collection="errorCode"` separately in the query.

Answer (score 0):

you can build a Context, like following:

```java
public class QueryConext {
    private String id ;
    private List<Example> examples;
    //get and set
}
public class Example {
   private String key;
   private Object value;
   //get and set
}
```

pass parameters like below

```java
//build QueryContext.
String load(QueryContext queryConext);
```