# Cannot get the result by passing the parameter to MyBatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a select `SQL` in `MyBatis` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE id IN (#{ids})
```

The parameter `ids` I passed in is correct, which I can get while I'm debugging. And also, I can run this `SQL` in `MySQL` with the parameter correctly and get the results.

But nothing is gotten running with `Java` code.

I printed the `SQL` of `MyBatis` and the `SQL` is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE id IN (?)
```

and the parameters shown in log is correct too(`'1', '2', '3'`).

Why can't I get the data by code?

I'd be appreciated if anyone can help.

Comment: Your parameter `ids` is which type? `String` or `List`?

Comment: Combine the ids into a `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `<foreach>` as [described in the documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#foreach).

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428742) other SO question if you are using annotations.

Comment: Thanks, Bogdan. This works. Is this the only way doing this? Can't I just pass in the parameter with `String`?

Comment: @Sky: Your SQL with a String just ends up like this: `WHERE id IN (?)`. What you actually want is something like this: `WHERE id IN (?, ?, ... ,?, ?)` which you get by iterating the list.

Comment: Yes, but I have the correct format for it, the parameter string is '1', '2', '3', exactly the one the `IN` parses.