# Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='childScanIDs', mode=IN, javaType

Tags: java, spring-boot, db2, mybatis

I tried this :

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE PRDCR_ID IN "
      + "FOREACH item= 'item'  index= 'index' collection= 'childScanIDs' separator=',' open='(' close=')'> #{item}  </FOREACH>") 
abstract List<String>  getCompanydetails(@Param("childScanIDs")  List<String> childScanIDs, @Param("groupName") String groupName);
```

**And I got the error below:**

> ```
> Could not set parameters for mapping:
> ```
>
> ParameterMapping{property='childScanIDs', mode=IN, javaType=class
> java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=null,
> resultMapId='null', jdbcTypeName='null', expression='null'}.
>
> Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null
> for parameter #1 with JdbcType null .
>
> Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different
> configuration property.
>
> Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null
> for parameter #1 with JdbcType null .
>
> Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different
> configuration property.
>
> Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error:
> SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=.;;, FROM INTO, DRIVER=4.14.137

Comment: There is an obvious mistake (missing open foreach tag) and inconsistent error messages in the question. I would suggest you to create a small demo project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues) that reproduces the exception and share it on your GitHub repo.

Comment: I have faced same issue.
"SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(sa_bd_cd) as SA_BD_CD, FROM DB2TADM.VGZ_AGT_PRDCR_INFO WHERE  PRDCR_ID IN  "
   + "<FOREACH item= 'item'  index= 'index' collection= 'childScanIDs' separator=',' open='(' close=')'> #{item}</FOREACH>"

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the only problem, but the entire statement must be enclosed in `<script>`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22646475/1261766).

Comment: Yes i have used <script> tag its working fine.